# wallpaperManager.setBitmap transition to black between old and new wallpapers

Tags: android

I try to change my wallpaper updating it with images from a server. I load those bitmaps to the memory, and then change them.

My problem is that I would like not to see the transition to black that appear when settig the Wallpaper but have a direct change between bitmaps. Is that possible?

```
try {
                    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(mapWall);
```

Comment: Overwriting an image in the memory may take some time, so I guess that's the reason of the black transition... Any creative solution to keep the old image until the new one is saved as a Wallpaper??

Comment: Did you find a solution? I've got the same problem in Android 5.0.2, when i set a new bitmap WallpaperManager setBitmap, the wallpaper keeps blinking between the old and new wallpaper

Comment: No, I didn't find a solution, is an Android feature lets say.